# Effect of router being bridged

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a Comcast modem with an embedded WiFi router.  I didn't wish to use their WiFi router, and had them "bridge" the device.  Downstream, I have a Netgear router, and I am using port forwarding to direct traffic to a Linux server on 192.168.0.200 for SFTP and HTTP (Yes, I know I am not suppose to be running a public webserver through Comcast, however, it is for development purposes only and password protected so no one ever visits it).

Everything was working great until I lost power which caused me to lose Internet.

I contacted Comcast, and the individual I talked to couldn't get it working as being bridged, and ultimately reset the router to its factory defaults, and did not enable bridging.  This brought back Internet to clients on my LAN, but I cannot remotely access the server.

I could access it directly from another client on my LAN (both a browser and a FTP client) using IP 192.168.0.200, so I know it is not iptables.

I can ping my server using myDomain.com, so I know my domain name is pointing to my server.
See the below output from nmap and nping.  Note that I am **not** forwarding Port 81, and it surprised and confused me that it looks the same as port 80 (not my question, but would like to know why).

My only thought is it relates to no longer being bridged, however, I don't really understand the implications of a router being bridged, and Comcast is not much help.

Please provide any suggestions.

```
[root@devserver ~]# nmap -p 80 myDomain.com

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-22 07:51 PDT
Nmap scan report for myDomain.com (12.345.103.53)
Host is up (0.0096s latency).
rDNS record for 12.345.103.53: c-98-232-103-53.hsd1.wa.comcast.net
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.35 seconds
[root@devserver ~]# nmap -p 81 myDomain.com

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-22 07:51 PDT
Nmap scan report for myDomain.com (12.345.103.53)
Host is up (0.0092s latency).
rDNS record for 12.345.103.53: c-98-232-103-53.hsd1.wa.comcast.net
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
81/tcp filtered hosts2-ns

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.35 seconds
[root@devserver ~]# nping -p 80 myDomain.com

Starting Nping 0.5.51 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2014-09-22 07:51 PDT
SENT (0.0529s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=27296 iplen=28
RCVD (0.0544s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1439 iplen=28
SENT (1.0530s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=27296 iplen=28
RCVD (1.0545s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1440 iplen=28
SENT (2.0546s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=27296 iplen=28
RCVD (2.0555s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1441 iplen=28
SENT (3.0566s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=27296 iplen=28
RCVD (3.0575s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1442 iplen=28
SENT (4.0586s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=27296 iplen=28
RCVD (4.0621s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1443 iplen=28

Max rtt: 3.466ms | Min rtt: 0.883ms | Avg rtt: 1.627ms
Raw packets sent: 5 (140B) | Rcvd: 5 (140B) | Lost: 0 (0.00%)
Tx time: 4.00576s | Tx bytes/s: 34.95 | Tx pkts/s: 1.25
Rx time: 5.00725s | Rx bytes/s: 27.96 | Rx pkts/s: 1.00
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 5.08 seconds
[root@devserver ~]# nping -p 81 myDomain.com

Starting Nping 0.5.51 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2014-09-22 07:52 PDT
SENT (0.0465s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=43653 iplen=28
RCVD (0.0476s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1444 iplen=28
SENT (1.0466s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=43653 iplen=28
RCVD (1.0477s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1445 iplen=28
SENT (2.0477s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=43653 iplen=28
RCVD (2.0535s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1446 iplen=28
SENT (3.0495s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=43653 iplen=28
RCVD (3.0507s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1447 iplen=28
SENT (4.0498s) ICMP 192.168.0.200 > 12.345.103.53 Echo request (type=8/code=0) ttl=64 id=43653 iplen=28
RCVD (4.0509s) ICMP 12.345.103.53 > 192.168.0.200 Echo reply (type=0/code=0) ttl=63 id=1448 iplen=28

Max rtt: 5.736ms | Min rtt: 1.006ms | Avg rtt: 1.984ms
Raw packets sent: 5 (140B) | Rcvd: 5 (140B) | Lost: 0 (0.00%)
Tx time: 4.00343s | Tx bytes/s: 34.97 | Tx pkts/s: 1.25
Rx time: 5.00449s | Rx bytes/s: 27.97 | Rx pkts/s: 1.00
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 5.07 seconds
[root@devserver ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood correctly..

Your network topology looks like this:

Comcast Router/Modem > Netgear Router (port forwarding) > Internal LAN

So the Comcast router in bridged mode basically disables NAT which translates your external IP 12.345.103.53 to your internal IP range of 192.168.0.x. What your seeing now is that the Comcast is doing the translation which means the port forwarding on the Netgear Router is not able to fulfill its duty because its being supplied with an internal IP range of 192.168.0.x rather than having the external IP passed through to it.

Depending on the make and model of the Comcast device will depend on how you enable 'bridge' mode and if its true bridge mode or another version of a similar function called transparent mode.

Are you able to log on to the router's web interface? Does it have any further details of the make and model for me to guide you getting this configured again?

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Yes, you understand correctly, and I think you are on to something.  My router is Nighthawk R6700, and I have access to the web interface.  What information do you need?  Or should I just tell Comcast to bridge it?

Comment: You can either tell them to bridge it and hopefully you get someone who can help better than the last guy.. I will also have a look at that model and see if I can find any guides on how the web interface looks (as I'm not familiar with it myself)... Out of interest does the Comcast plug directly in to the WAN port on the Netgear?

Comment: Coax to Comcast modem/router, Comcast Port 1 (when bridged, now any works) to Netgear Router WAN.  Thanks

Comment: Are you aware if the Netgear settings have been reset? Easiest way to tell is to see if the WiFi is still broadcasting?

Comment: The Netgear settings should not have been reset.  Yes, Netgear is still broadcasting.

Comment: Aside from getting them to bridge it again, you can also try to have them port forward 80 and 22 from the comcast to the internal NAT'd IP your netgear is getting. I'd also recommend you take the current WAN DHCP-provided settings on the netgear and configure them as static so you don't get it jumping around once your lease expires.

Comment: @user1032531 Have you had any joy getting this setup again?